# Can we change the domcfg.nsf sigIn button to call Lotus agent first for custom validation

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

I am trying to create a two way authentication in Lotus Notes Webamil. I have configured the domcfg.nsf login. I wanted that when user click sigin button my custom validation are called first through agent and than it is redirected to redirection page.
this url was used by us to configure Lotus web Mail on our server.
https://aacable.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/howto-enable-webmail-inotes-in-ibm-lotus-domain-8-5/
Is it possible to customise the sign in process.

Please help. Please

Answer (score 2):

I have my doubts about the possibility of triggering a custom agent to handle web signon for Domino. I'm not necessarily saying it's impossible, but the normal path for customizing web authentication for Domino servers is by using the DSAPI feature of the [Lotus Notes C API Toolkit](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/capi/).  See chapter 9-11 of the API User Guide for more details.